# Get actual DateTime independent of SystemTime

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0

**Objective:** I'm developing an application that can work in online as well as offline. The app has a feature to create and save the NOTES inside the application. Also, the app need internet connection for the first time it get open.  After that, it can work in offline mode, it will send all the Notes once the app get the internet connection

**ISSUE:** I need to send the exact "Date Created" field along with the NOTES to the server.  "Date Created" time has to be exact one even the system time is wrong.

I have correct time from the server when the app connect to the internet for the first time. Is it possible to track the time independent of system time with the time we get for the first time from server even the app get closed or system get rebooted.

I tried with  `PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"`which give the system uptime.  I am able to track the time even the app get closed.  But not able to track if the user rebooted the system.

Also,  I need to track correct time even the user changes the system time intentionally in offline mode. Is there any callback func for this in C#?

**Note:** I'm using SQLlite as backend, Is there anything I can do with this?

Comment: For the first time when connect with the internet, take current GMT time from the server. Store this at client side. and Also save the difference between Server GMT time - Client GMT at client side. Whenever user create a new note, save your time as current user GMT time - difference. If you want to cover the case when client changes his timezone in between, which is rare, in that case you would need to save one file at client side. Use date last modified option to track, which is more complicated.

Comment: Are you trying to deal with accidentally wrong timestamps or an actively hostile user?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever For both :P

Comment: For actively hostile users, your only line of defence lies in code that you've not placed on that user's machine - i.e. that's safely sitting on your server. So if you need assured, unforgeable timestamps you need to drop the requirement for off-line mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options you could *consider*:

- Use `Stopwatch`, which is designed for measuring elapsed times. Start that when you retrieve the server time, and then you can add the elapsed time to the server time whenever you need to. However, I don't know what happens if you suspend to a `Stopwatch` if someone suspends the machine.
- Note the system clock's value (using `DateTime.UtcNow` - don't get local times involved here) when you retrieve the server time, and compare the two to get a delta between the two clocks. You can apply the delta any time you want to get a prediction of what the server clock would say. Caveats with this approach:

  - If the local clock is running slow or fast (or being adjusted by something like the Windows Time service), the delta could become incorrect.
  - If the user adjusts the system local clock, you'll have problems.

Basically without an internet connection, the only time source you've got is the local system. How much of a problem that is depends on what failure modes you're worried about - if it's just a matter of *convenience* for the notes to have the right time, and you don't need to worry about malicious users changing the clock, that's probably not too much of a problem. If you absolutely need an accurate, independent timestamp, then you're basically stuck.

(Of course, you can refine these schemes slightly by *repeatedly* taking the server time and comparing it with whatever you would expect it to be - that could help detect tampering or incidental drift. But at some point you'll go offline, and there's not a lot you can do between then and the next time you're online.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UTC date instead of normal get date function

In c#

```
DateTime.UTCNow
```

In Sql server

```
getutcdate()
```